# Don't split double-quoted words with Python string split()?

Tags: python, string, split

When using the Python string function split(), does anybody have a nifty trick to treat items surrounded by double-quotes as a non-splitting word?

Say I want to split only on white space and I have this:

```
>>> myStr = 'A B\t"C" DE "FE"\t\t"GH I JK L" "" ""\t"O P   Q" R'
>>> myStr.split()
['A', 'B', '"C"', 'DE', '"FE"', '"GH', 'I', 'JK', 'L"', '""', '""', '"O', 'P', 'Q"', 'R']
```

I'd like to treat anything within double-quotes as a single word, even if white spaces are embedded, so would like to end up with the below:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'DE', 'FE', 'GH I JK L', '', '', 'O P   Q', 'R']
```

Or at least this and then I'll strip off the double-quotes:

```
['A', 'B', '"C"', 'DE', '"FE"', '"GH I JK L"', '""', '""', '"O P   Q"', 'R']
```

Any non-regex suggestions?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You won't be able to get this behaviour with `str.split()`.  If you can live with the rather complex parsing it does (like ignoring double quotes preceded by a back slash), [`shlex.split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html) might be what you are looking for:

```
>>> shlex.split(myStr)
['A', 'B', 'C', 'DE', 'FE', 'GH I JK L', '', '', 'O P   Q', 'R']
```

Answer (score 4):

@Rob: why without regexes if the regexp solution is so simple?

```
my_str = 'A B\t"C" DE "FE"\t\t"GH I JK L" "" ""\t"O P   Q" R'
print re.findall(r'(\w+|".*?")', my_str)
['A', 'B', '"C"', 'DE', '"FE"', '"GH I JK L"', '""', '""', '"O P   Q"', 'R']
```

Comment: @PabloG - Despite often being the upfront easy solution, I have yet to personally encounter a case where regex didn't have more long term costs.

As for this specific case, I was pretty certain this was a solved problem and I just could find it --- appears Sven pointed me in the right direction with shlex.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you search with `re` for the pattern "[^"]*" and apply string.split only on the remaining parts. You could implement a recursive function that processes all relevant string parts.