# split strings and save comma int python

Tags: python, string, split

I have the following string

```
c='a,b,c,"d,e",f,g'
```

and I want to get

```
b=['a','b','c','d,e','f','g']
```

so

```
b[3]=='d,e'
```

any ideas? the problem with `c.split(',')` is that it splits also `'d,e'`

[I have see an answer here for C++, that of course didn't help me]

Many Thanks

Comment: isn't it c = 'a,b,c,"d,e",f,g'?

Comment: what you got is not even a string as it has to start and end either with `'` or  `"`

Comment: This question http://stackoverflow.com/q/7881794/1353098 has an alternate solution for when more string parsing needs to take place.

Comment: If what you're really trying to do is read a CSV file, then you should say so.

Comment: @Will, How would you use `shlex.split()` in this case?

Comment: My bad, I thought you could set the token that `shlex.split` used to split parameters.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use the CSV module if `c` should indeed be the below...

```
import csv
c = 'a,b,c,"d,e",f,g'
print next(csv.reader([c]))
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd,e', 'f', 'g']
```

Comment: Nice one. Hadn't seen this one before.